# Array to ListBox conversion

Tags: arrays, vba, listbox

I have an integer array with 5 numbers. I would like to copy these numbers to a `ListBox`, with following code. `ListBox1` is on a `UserForm`.

```
ListBox1.AddItem (SampleArray(i).tostring)
```

I have got this error:

> Compile error: Invalid qualifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop and add each item individually

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(SampleArray) To UBound(SampleArray)
    ListBox1.AddItem SampleArray(i)
Next
```

The error is because `SampleArray(i)` is an integer type which does not implement a `ToString` method - nothing in base VBA does (don't confuse it with VB.Net).